# How to force execution of transition on browser refresh with spring webflow

Tags: ajax, transition, spring-webflow, browser-refresh

Here is the situation: In a page I send data to the backend using ajax. This all works fine, it stores the information in the database as it should and all. Now when I press the refresh button on the browser, it still contains the old data (I don't update the form manually). The reason for this I think it is because my transition is never fired since the refresh is not part of the flow. How can I force reloading the form? How do you define such in the flow xml?

below is part of the webflow xml

```
<action-state id="showProposal">
    <evaluate expression="portfolioAction.showProposalFormAction" />
    <transition on="success" to="showProposalView" />       
</action-state>

<view-state id="showProposalView" view="/swf/proposal/proposal">
    <transition on="storeProposal" to="storeProposalView" >
        <evaluate expression="portfolioAction.storeProposalFormAction" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="applySelection" to="showProposalView">
        <evaluate expression="portfolioForm.bindAndValidate" />
        <evaluate expression="portfolioAction.showProposalFormAction" />
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you put your logic in the [`on-render`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#view-on-render) section of your `view-state`?

> Use the on-render element to execute one or more actions before view rendering. Render actions are executed on the initial render as well as any subsequent refreshes, including any partial re-renderings of the view.